# GS013 error when executing Gnosis Safe transaction for function of MultiSig Wallet

Tags: gas, gnosis-safe, gnosis, avax, avalanche

Me and another owner were recently transferred team tokens for a protocol we just became new owners of. This is currently on AVAX NETWORK.

In the protocol, there is a claim function to claim linearly vested team tokens vested for 180 days. This claim function is currently linked to previous owners wallet and we would like to change the claim address to our multi-sig address.

Upon setting the address to our multisig wallet through snowtrace, 2/2 signers have confirmed the transaction in Gnosis Safe.

When trying to execute the transaction I get the following error message: This transaction will most likely fail. To save gas costs, avoid creating the transaction.

And when proceeding anyway, incl manually setting the gas limit, I get the GS013 error: Safe transaction failed when gasPrice and safeTxGas were 0

We have conducted the transaction many times to which it failed.

We've also been told that gnosis had a problem estimating gas, and was wondering if you knew any 3rd party dApp for avax that might help solve this.

If anybody can help, please do let me know.

I can provide more details.

Transaction: https://snowtrace.io/tx/0xe651815a6b8019f2ea59965d77923b2a4b54767e38de169c5b4b346781f77285

Our multisig wallet: https://snowtrace.io/address/0x119ffddd541129f096884192452c89f29eec23f8

Previous owner wallet linked to community/dev fund: https://snowtrace.io/tokenholdings?a=0x45603d531c38c41cfc294511526683cd7326c66d

Contract we're trying to change addresses for: https://snowtrace.io/address/0xffe04bf98c7111360bf7a6c56b343915543cd941#writeContract

Attached below is the write function of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

gs013 means that the transaction reverted in the contract you interacted with. you can use tenderly for debugging

Comment: I'm on avax network. will it still work? 

If so what feature on tenderly am i supposed to use?

Comment: yes, it will work. please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90GN9Ut8LhU

Comment: Appreciate it! will look into it and update if anything.

Comment: Can you help me interpret what this means? 

function setDevFund(address _devFund) external {
        require(msg.sender == devFund, "!dev");
        require(_devFund != address(0), "zero");