# How to get exact error from contract instead of GS013 error?

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature, gnosis

I am getting GS013 error if transaction on deployed contracts fails, which is fired through gnosis multisig. I want to get the exact error instead of gs013 on reverting. Can I use simulateTxAccesor contract for that ? How to use return value from simulate function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GS013 error when executing Gnosis Safe transaction for function of MultiSig Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125832/gs013-error-when-executing-gnosis-safe-transaction-for-function-of-multisig-wall)

Comment: No, I can use tenderly for debugging, but I need error via web3 functions to save it in DB.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.